# Hosting service with WordPress auto-install

Tags: hosting, wordpress

I recently started a WordPress blog on MyDomain (which offers WordPress auto-installation). Being a newbie to hosted blogging, I prefer using a host service that will have WordPress auto-installation.

I'm very disappointed with MyDomain because of two key issues they failed me on:

1. I have no access to .htaccess files so I can't use "nice" permalinks.
2. The WordPress application can't access WordPress.com or akismet, so I'm very limited in the plugins I can use.

I'm considering switching a hosting service to get better WordPress service. Is there any service that "plays nicely" with auto-installed WordPress out of the box?

On WordPress.org they mention BlueHost, DreamHost and some others, however these are (I assume) paid featured hosts, so although I would like to support WordPress.org, I don't trust these commercials.

What's the best option for me?

Thanks

Comment: Are you only going to use WordPress on your host?  Why not just get sign up at WordPress.com?

Comment: @squillman: I want more flexibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I chose [JustHost](http://www.justhost.com) that were quite cheap and recommended by WordPress.org. Meanwhile everything is okay, thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I have hosting in a few different hosting companies, one of which is DreamHost. There are some horror stories about them, but I've never had an issue with them. And their WordPress auto-installation is very smooth.

Comment: Regarding their WordPress hosting - do you know if they provide access to .htaccess files and allow for outbound connections? Thanks

Comment: Yes, yes they do.

Comment: I didn't choose them because of the minimal required payment. I thought it to bee too much (50$ to be able to pay monthly or pre-pay 1 year in advance)

Answer (score 0):

I use Hostmonster.com  .  It has the newest version of **cPanel Pro**  and it has the latest version of many of the most popular web softwares, including WordPress.    They charge $5.95 a month for UNLIMITED space and bandwidth.   Also, they have Live Chat with support on their site so you can easily ask questions about the service.   http://www.hostmonster.com/

Comment: Is that really unlimited, or "unlimited" bandwidth?

Comment: they have a few hundred "shared servers" and so you get all the bandwidth you need.  they dont charge you for going over any limit.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want wordpress hosting go with [wordpress.com](http://wordpress.com)

Comment: it you go with auto-hosting a blog, i'd say typepad.com is good also.